# resume audio phonegap

Tags: javascript, cordova

hey guys i am using the media phonegap api to play,pause and stop the audio. so far i managed to play,stop and pause, but i do not know how to resume please help me

below is the code i have written till now

```
   var my_media = null;
    var mediaTimer = null;
     var pausePos = 0;
    var counter=0;
    var playing=false;


   function playAudio(src) {
// Create Media object from src
my_media = new Media(src, onSuccess, onError);

// Play audio

 my_media.play();


  // get audio duration
var duration =  my_media.getDuration();

// set slider data
if( duration > 0 ){
    $('#slider').attr( 'max', Math.round(duration) );
    $('#slider').slider('refresh');
}



// Update my_media position every second
if (mediaTimer == null) {
    mediaTimer = setInterval(function() {
        // get my_media position
        my_media.getCurrentPosition(
            // success callback
            function(position) {
                if (position > -1) {
                    setAudioPosition(position);
                }
            },
            // error callback
            function(e) {
                console.log("Error getting pos=" + e);
                setAudioPosition("Error: " + e);
            }
        );
    }, 1000);
}
```

}

```
  /* pause audio */
   function pauseAudio() {
     if (my_media) {
    my_media.pause();
     }
    }

function resumeAudio()
   {

 }

 /* stop audio */
    function stopAudio() {
if (my_media) {
    my_media.stop();
    playing = false;
    my_media.release();
     }
clearInterval(mediaTimer);
mediaTimer = null;
pausePos = 0;
 }




    // onSuccess Callback

   function onSuccess() {
console.log("playAudio():Audio Success");
  }

  // onError Callback

   function onError(error) {
       alert('code: '    + error.code    + '\n' +
    'message: ' + error.message + '\n');
 }

    // Set audio position

   function setAudioPosition(position) {
          pausePos = position;
          position = Math.round(position);
          $('#slider').val(position);
         $('#slider').slider('refresh');
     }


   function player(id)
     {
         //alert(id);
         playAudio("/sdcard/MuseumCache/"+id+"/"+id+".mp3");
          //alert("end");
    }
```

Please help me to write the resume function. they said the media.play() plays and resumes playing audio file

Answer (score 1):

ok I fond the solution: Phonegap's Docs are terrible...badly explained
so their example is sloppy

the point is: you must not reinitialize the media everytime you play otherwise it starts form beginning

```
var my_media == null;
function playAudio(url) {
          if (my_media === null){
                // so only is your media handler is empty you initialiaze it otherwise you just play
                            my_media = new Media(url, function() {
                                console.log("Audio Success");
                            }, function(err) {
                                console.log("Audio Error");
                            });
          }
          my_media.play();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As per the documentation of PhoneGap **media.play** starts or **resume** the audio file.

```
media.play: Start or resume playing audio file.
```

you can find the link [here](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.0.0/phonegap_media_media.md.html)

Comment: I have the same problem and when I pause an audio file it restarts from zero when I click play...

Answer (score 0):

Francesco your solution work only if you have one sound to play, if you have multi sound on the same page each player will get the property of the first media...